# Kohana 3.1 ORM DB Query

Tags: php, sql, database, orm, kohana-3

I have app in Kohana 3.1 and it was woring fine on PHP 5.4

But after migration this DB query is not working:

`DB::select(array('MAX("art_nr")', 'art_nr'))->from('wi_artykuly')->execute()->get('art_nr');`

If any function is depricated or something?

EDIT

Here's full function:

```
 public function create(Validation $validation = NULL)
{
    if(! isset($this->art_nr))
    {
        $intMax = DB::select(array('MAX("art_nr")', 'art_nr'))->from('wi_artykuly')->execute()->get('art_nr');
        $this->art_nr = $intMax+1;
    }
    return parent::create($validation);
}
```

Comment: Add the 'sql' tag to this question.

Comment: Thanks, don't you know how to fix it though? You seem like smart one.

Comment: I don't know how to fix it.  I was just moderating this question, that's all.

Comment: Please can you amend your question and include the error message being thrown, and also what version of PHP you are now using, if different from PHP 5.4? I should be able to help you then.

Comment: I am using PHP 5.6 now. I don't get any error, but It only return 1. I will include whole code in question

Comment: Allright I did managed to change whole stuff using PDO fetch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've changed DB:query to PDO prepare and fetch.

If anyone wants a code please write.